# Locally finite covers of metrizable space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metrizable space. How to define a sequence $\mathfrak{U}_{1}, \mathfrak{U}_{2}, \ldots$ of locally finite open covers of the $X$ such that each member of $\mathfrak{U}_{i}$ has diameter less than $1/i$ and can be represented as the union of members of $\mathfrak{U}_{i+1}$?

I tried to use the Stone theorem, but i don't know how to represent members of $\mathfrak{U}_{i}$ exactly as the union of members of $\mathfrak{U}_{i+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Idea:

Let $\mathfrak{U}_1$ be a locally finite cover of open sets refining the cover of all balls of radius $\frac{1}{2}$. (This uses Stone's theorem).
Each member $U \in \mathfrak{U}_1$ sits inside some such ball and thus has diameter $<1$. Now within each $U \in \mathfrak{U}_1$ do the same: a locally finite refinement of a "small enough" open cover of subsets (which can be done by openness and the fact that $U$ as a subspace also is metrisable and so paracompact). Collect all these covers for each $U$ together, and note the result is still locally finite. This gives us $\mathfrak{U}_2$ and now proceed by standard recursion.

Comment: Excuse me, i can't understand why "result is still locally finite". For example, on real line $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(0,1/i)$ is locally finite cover of $(0,1)$, but $0$ has no neighborhood, that intersect only finite number of such intervals. Сould you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: @IlyaOblomov then take an extra locally finite refinement step.

Comment: it seems to me that this will not help, or i don't understand something.